# Will variable in function be destroyed after function run?

Tags: php, class, memory

Will variable in function be destroyed after function run?

```
class B {
   function C() {
       $x = "123456";
       echo "XXX".$x;
       // After this function is finished, will $x be destroyed by default to save memory in PHP?
   }
}
class A {
   function F1() {
       return new Class_B();
   }

   function F2() {
       $this->F1()->C();
       // After this function is finished, will F1 be destroyed by default to save memory and CPU in PHP?
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it will be, unless you make it a `static` variable, or make it a member of the class. e.g. `$B::x`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php garbage collection basics straight out from the php manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `$x`: yes, it will be subject to garbage collection after `B::C()` finishes running.

Regarding `$this->F1()->C()`: the `F1` method itself won't be destroyed, but the instance of `B` returned by it will be destroyed after `F2` finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be "destroyed" so that the memory it took up can be reused.